# Foreach loop shows only the last row

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I created an email placeholder (#_DATATABEL) for the plugin Events Manager. This placeholder must show the repeater fields from customized fields from Advanced Custom Fields Pro.

In this case, the loop shows only the last row. There are four rows/results in total.

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
    //
    // Create new placeholder | events manager email
    //
    add_filter('em_event_output_placeholder', 'datatable_placeholders', 1, 3);
    function datatable_placeholders($replace, $EM_Event, $result) {
        if($result == '#_DATATABEL') {
            $current_event_id = $EM_Event->output("#_EVENTPOSTID");
            $replace = 'none';
            //$EM_Event = new EM_Event($cursus_id);

            $replace = create_data_table_mail($current_event_id);
        }
        return $replace;
    }

    function create_data_table_mail($current_event_id) {
        if(get_field('gekoppelde_cursus_leergang', $current_event_id)) {

            $loop = get_field('gekoppelde_cursus_leergang', $current_event_id);
            foreach($loop as $sub_field) {
                $resultaat = $sub_field['cursus_leergang'];
            }
        }
        return $resultaat;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, in the loop foreach you only get the last result.
Try using an array instead `$resultaat`

Comment: $resultaat is assigned each iteration of your loop. Use concatenate `$resultaat .=` or an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function create_data_table_mail($current_event_id) {
    if(get_field('gekoppelde_cursus_leergang', $current_event_id)) {

        $loop = get_field('gekoppelde_cursus_leergang', $current_event_id);
        $arr = array();
        foreach($loop as $sub_field ) {
            $arr[] = $sub_field['cursus_leergang'];
        }
    }
    return $arr;
```

Your *foreach* loop iterates through all items from $sub_field and overrides $resultaat every time. After that, you return the last $resultaat. Try to use a list or an array and add the results to it, and then return the list or array.